# Is there any API to create Apps for Integration Key using API

Tags: docusignapi

We have been using  DocuSign.eSign.Api. Is there any

1) API/ Method to create new app, and

2) API/ method to retrieve integrationKey for existing apps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to become a partner of DocuSign, an ISV that manages other accounts and applications, and get special reseller status.

Check out 
https://partners.docusign.com/s/
For more information.